# getting the current duration of recorded video using PBJVision

Tags: ios, video, camera

How can I get the length of the video session in seconds?

I understand that I may have to do some sort of conversion of CMTime in `didCaptureVideoSampleBuffer`, but I can't seem to find the right property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

inside `didCaptureVideoSampleBuffer` I put

`NSLog(@"%f",[[PBJVision sharedInstance] capturedVideoSeconds]);`

Comment: Does this work for you? It's only giving negative values for some reason.